# This macro will convert you... or not

Tags: performance, vba

I'm developing a macro that converts a text file, hence the attempt for a funny title, or cringy, opinions may vary!

## Context and Objectives

I was assigned a project to replace a old legacy program whose our contract is about to expire.
This program accepted a text file for input and splits it into a new file based on a couple of parameters.

The text file does not have a clear structure, meaning that just separating with spaces, tabs or commas does not produce a clean file with all data.

So the objective of my macro is to input the text file and treat it, and separate it according to a spec, special format for a single case where there's a extra space and normalize it, and finally write to CSV.

As far as speed goes, I am not happy at all with it. **It takes about 17 secs to

read, convert and output for a 4MB file**, which has about 24 000 lines.

Probably I am doing some extra code that can be truncated and improved, but I need your wise eyes to help me.

**Also, I've already run Rubberduck Build 2.0.11.**

The test data and add-in:

- [Test file (macro-enabled Excel workbook download)](https://ufile.io/v7fa4)

There's some really basic error handling in here, I am learning custom error handling now, but I haven't include it here.

**Upfront apologies for the length of the post.**

## Code

- Outside from any sub, on top

  ```
  Option Explicit
  '@Ignore EncapsulatePublicField, MoveFieldCloserToUsage
  Public progressBarCount As Long
  ```
- Starting from the main sub that holds all the smaller functions. I've chosen this logic because it runs the procedures in a sequence and doesn't run unnecessary functions.

  ```
  Public Sub ConvertPanel()

  Dim startCell As Range
  Dim readMethod As Variant
  Dim convertString As Variant
  Dim finalProcessor As Variant

  Dim specString As String
  Dim filePath As String

  ExcelOptimization (True)

  Set startCell = Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, 1))
  specString = GetSpecString
  filePath = GetFilePath

  If ValidateSpecString(specString) Then
      If ValidateInputFile(filePath) Then
              convertString = ConvertSpecString(specString)
              readMethod = QuickRead(filePath)
              finalProcessor = SplitColumns(readMethod, convertString, startCell)
              If finalProcessor Then
                  If FormatYear Then
                      If FormatAutocomm Then
                          If FormatID Then
                              If FormatHA Then
                                  If FormatProv Then
                                      If AddHeader Then
                                          If ReplaceSpaces Then
                                              If CleanupSpaces Then
                                                  If WriteOutputCSV Then
                                                      ExcelOptimization (False)
                                                      MsgBox "Process completed and file generated!", vbOKOnly, "Complete!"
                                                      Exit Sub
                                                  End If
                                              End If
                                          End If
                                      End If
                                  End If
                              End If
                          End If
                      End If
                  End If
              End If
      End If
  End If   

  End Sub
  ```

---

- Small performance improvement sub

  ```
  Private Sub ExcelOptimization(ByVal turnState As Boolean)

  If turnState Then
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      Columns.AutoFit
  Else
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
      Application.EnableEvents = True
      ThisWorkbook.Activate
      ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
  End If

  End Sub
  ```

---

- This function defines how the text file should be splitted.

  ```
  Private Function GetSpecString() As String

      Dim customSpecString As Long
      customSpecString = MsgBox("Do you want to use default spec string?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Custom spec string")

      If customSpecString = vbNo Then
          GetSpecString = Application.InputBox("Enter your custom string", "Custom string builder", Type:=2)

          If GetSpecString = False Then
              MsgBox "No string was chosen. The default string will be used."
              GetSpecString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,2,@|29,2,@|34,1"
              Exit Function
          End If
      Else
          GetSpecString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,2,@|29,2,@|34,1"
          Exit Function
      End If

  End Function
  ```

---

- Standard open file from windows explorer

  ```
  Private Function GetFilePath() As String

      Dim choiceNumber As Long

      Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).AllowMultiSelect = False
      choiceNumber = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show

      If choiceNumber <> 0 Then
          GetFilePath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
          Exit Function
      Else
          MsgBox "No file was chosen. Please re-check!", vbCritical, "Error - no file selected"
          GetFilePath = vbNullString
          Exit Function
      End If

      Exit Function

  End Function
  ```

---

- Basic validation for split string ( called spec string )

  ```
  Private Function ValidateSpecString(ByVal specString As String) As Boolean

       If Len(specString) < 3 Then
          MsgBox "No spec found. Please re-check.", vbCritical, "Error"
          ValidateSpecString = False
          Exit Function
       End If

      If specString = vbNullString Then
          MsgBox "Field specs are incorrect or missing. Aborting!", vbCritical, "Error"
          ValidateSpecString = False
          Exit Function
      End If

      If InStr(specString, "|") = 0 Then
          MsgBox "Please specify that you have at least 2 fields. Example: 1,10|2,10"
          ValidateSpecString = False
          Exit Function
      End If

      ValidateSpecString = True

  End Function
  ```

---

- Basic validation for input file

  ```
  Private Function ValidateInputFile(ByVal fileName As String) As Boolean

       If Dir(fileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
          MsgBox "No file found.", vbCritical, "Error"
          ValidateInputFile = False
          Exit Function
       End If

      ValidateInputFile = True

  End Function
  ```

---

- Function to convert the input spec string to an array to use later

  ```
  Private Function ConvertSpecString(ByVal specString As String) As String()

          Dim fieldsInfo() As String
          Dim inputString As String

          inputString = Replace(specString, Space(1), vbNullString)
          fieldsInfo = Split(inputString, "|")
          ConvertSpecString = fieldsInfo

  End Function
  ```

---

- Function to read the file that should be quick which I've adapted it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376756/what-is-a-superfast-way-to-read-large-files-line-by-line-in-vba)

  ```
  Private Function QuickRead(ByVal fileName As String) As String()

      Dim fileNumber As Long
      Dim stringRes As String
      Dim fileSize As Long

      fileNumber = FreeFile
      fileSize = FileLen(fileName)
      stringRes = Space(fileSize)

      Open fileName For Binary Access Read As #fileNumber
          Get #fileNumber, , stringRes
      Close fileNumber

      QuickRead = Split(stringRes, vbCrLf)

  End Function
  ```

---

- Main engine of the project, grabs everything from text file and splits into excel spreadsheet from the spec string. You'll notice that there's a special case for a number '822343', which is the only case where there's an extra space that shouldn't be there and thus "fixed" like that. Also I use a class for a progress bar which I only adapted, but the main conception is from [Zack Graber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181164/progress-bar-in-vba-excel).

  ```
  Private Function SplitColumns(ByVal lineArray As Variant, ByVal fieldsInfo As Variant, ByVal startCell As Range) As Boolean

      Dim indexCount As Long
      Dim stringRange As Range
      Dim fileInfo() As String
      Dim counterColumns As Long
      Dim counterRows As Long
      Dim counterOfElements As Long
      Dim numberOfElements As Long
      Dim lastRowCounter As Long
      '@Ignore SelfAssignedDeclaration
      Dim progressBar As New progressBar
      Dim convertedString As String

      Dim startTime As Double
      Dim secondsElapsed As Double
      startTime = Timer

      Set stringRange = startCell
      numberOfElements = 17

      counterRows = 1
      counterColumns = 1

      With ActiveSheet
          lastRowCounter = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
      End With

      For indexCount = LBound(lineArray) To UBound(lineArray)

              For counterOfElements = 0 To numberOfElements - 1

                  If Left$(lineArray(indexCount), 6) = "822343" Then

                      convertedString = Left$(lineArray(indexCount), 37) & Mid$(lineArray(indexCount), 39, Len(lineArray(indexCount)) + 1)
                      fileInfo = Split(fieldsInfo(counterOfElements), ",")
                      stringRange.EntireRow.Cells(counterRows, counterColumns).Value = Mid$(convertedString, CLng(fileInfo(0)), CLng(fileInfo(1)))
                      counterColumns = counterColumns + 1

                  Else

                      fileInfo = Split(fieldsInfo(counterOfElements), ",")
                      stringRange.EntireRow.Cells(counterRows, counterColumns).Value = Mid$(lineArray(indexCount), CLng(fileInfo(0)), CLng(fileInfo(1)))
                      counterColumns = counterColumns + 1

                  End If
              Next counterOfElements

              counterColumns = 1
              counterRows = counterRows + 1

              If UBound(lineArray) < 100 Then
                  If UBound(lineArray) = 1 Then
                      progressBarCount = 100
                  Else
                      progressBarCount = (counterRows * 100) / lastRowCounter
                  End If
              Else
                  progressBarCount = (counterRows * 100) / UBound(lineArray)
              End If

              If UBound(lineArray) = 0 Then
                  progressBarCount = 0
              End If

              progressBar.Update progressBarCount, 100, "Processing records", True
      Next indexCount

      SplitColumns = True
      secondsElapsed = Round(Timer - startTime, 2)
      MsgBox "Macro run in " & secondsElapsed & " seconds."

  End Function
  ```

---

- For the next couple of functions, I just format specific fields that are needed for our database system **(please let me know if I should remove these).**

  ```
  Private Function FormatYear() As Boolean

  Dim maxRowNumber As Long
  Dim rowNumber    As Long

  On Error GoTo FormatYearErrHandler

      maxRowNumber = (Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
      For rowNumber = 1 To maxRowNumber
              Cells(rowNumber, 4).Value = Cells(rowNumber, 4).Value & Format$(Cells(rowNumber, 5).Value, "00")
      Next rowNumber
      Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
      FormatYear = True
      Exit Function

  FormatYearErrHandler:
  FormatYear = False
  Exit Function

  End Function
  ```

---

```
Private Function FormatAutocomm() As Boolean

    Dim maxRowNumber As Long
    Dim rowNumber    As Long
    Dim valueString As String

    On Error GoTo FormatAutocommErrHandler
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
        maxRowNumber = Cells(Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp).Row

        For rowNumber = 1 To maxRowNumber
                valueString = Format$(Cells(rowNumber, 11).Value, "00")
                Cells(rowNumber, 11).NumberFormat = "@"
                Cells(rowNumber, 11).Value = valueString
                valueString = vbNullString
        Next rowNumber

        FormatAutocomm = True
        Exit Function

FormatAutocommErrHandler:
    FormatAutocomm = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

---

```
Private Function FormatID() As Boolean

    Dim maxRowNumber As Long
    Dim rowNumber    As Long

    On Error GoTo FormatIDErrHandler

        maxRowNumber = (Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        For rowNumber = 1 To maxRowNumber
                Cells(rowNumber, 1).Value = Cells(rowNumber, 1) * 1
        Next rowNumber
        FormatID = True
        Exit Function

FormatIDErrHandler:
    FormatID = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

---

```
Private Function FormatHA() As Boolean

    Dim maxRowNumber As Long
    Dim rowNumber    As Long
    Dim valueString As String

    On Error GoTo FormatAutocommErrHandler
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
        maxRowNumber = Cells(Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

        For rowNumber = 1 To maxRowNumber
                valueString = Format$(Cells(rowNumber, 14).Value, "00")
                Cells(rowNumber, 14).NumberFormat = "@"
                Cells(rowNumber, 14).Value = valueString
                valueString = vbNullString
        Next rowNumber

        FormatHA = True
        Exit Function

FormatAutocommErrHandler:
    FormatHA = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

---

```
Private Function FormatProv() As Boolean

    Dim maxRowNumber As Long
    Dim rowNumber    As Long
    Dim valueString As String

    On Error GoTo FormatAutocommErrHandler
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
        maxRowNumber = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

        For rowNumber = 1 To maxRowNumber
                valueString = Format$(Cells(rowNumber, 15).Value, "00")
                Cells(rowNumber, 15).NumberFormat = "@"
                Cells(rowNumber, 15).Value = valueString
                valueString = vbNullString
        Next rowNumber

        FormatProv = True
        Exit Function

FormatAutocommErrHandler:
    FormatProv = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

---

- Adding some headers

  ```
  Private Function AddHeader() As Boolean

      Dim arr(1 To 16) As String
      On Error GoTo AddHeaderErrHandler

      arr(1) = "a"
      arr(2) = "b"
      arr(3) = "c"
      arr(4) = "d"
      arr(5) = "f"
      arr(6) = "g"
      arr(7) = "h"
      arr(8) = "i"
      arr(9) = "j"
      arr(10) = "k"
      arr(11) = "l"
      arr(12) = "m"
      arr(13) = "n"
      arr(14) = "o"
      arr(15) = "p"
      arr(16) = "q"

      With Worksheets(1)
          .Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert
          .Range("A1:P1") = arr()
      End With

      AddHeader = True
      Exit Function
  AddHeaderErrHandler:
      AddHeader = False
      Exit Function

  End Function
  ```

---

- Cleaning up data for sparse spaces

  ```
  Private Function ReplaceSpaces() As Boolean

      Dim MyArray As Variant
      Dim rowCountArray As Long, columnCountArray As Long

      MyArray = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

      For rowCountArray = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
          For columnCountArray = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
              If MyArray(rowCountArray, columnCountArray) <> vbNullString Then
                  If InStr(1, MyArray(rowCountArray, columnCountArray), " ") > 0 Then
                      Cells(rowCountArray, columnCountArray).Value = WorksheetFunction.Substitute(MyArray(rowCountArray, columnCountArray), " ", "0")
                  End If
              End If
          Next columnCountArray
      Next rowCountArray

      ReplaceSpaces = True
  End Function
  ```

---

- Cleaning up data after used range, to prevent when writing csv to show up blanks

  ```
  Private Function CleanupSpaces() As Boolean

      Dim fileWorksheet As Worksheet

      Dim lastRow As Long
      Dim lastColumn As Long
      Dim usedRows As Long
      Dim usedColumns As Long

      Set fileWorksheet = ActiveSheet

      With fileWorksheet

          lastRow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
          lastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
          usedRows = .UsedRange.Row + .UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
          usedColumns = .UsedRange.Column + .UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
          .Range(.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn + 1), .Cells(lastRow + usedRows, lastColumn + usedColumns + 1)).Clear

     End With

      CleanupSpaces = True

  End Function
  ```

---

- Finally, generating CSV file

  ```
  Private Function WriteOutputCSV() As Boolean

      Dim fileName As String
      Dim fileDelimiter As String
      Dim fileString As String
      Dim fileLastRow As Long
      Dim fileLastCol As Long
      Dim counterRow As Long
      Dim counterCol As Long
      Dim binaryStream As ADODB.Stream
      Dim fileWorksheet As Worksheet

      Const adSaveCreateOverWrite As Variant = 2

      Set fileWorksheet = ActiveSheet
      Set binaryStream = New ADODB.Stream

      fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(vbNullString, "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")
      fileDelimiter = ";"

      counterRow = 1
      counterCol = 1
      binaryStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
      binaryStream.Type = 2
      binaryStream.Open

      With fileWorksheet
          fileLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
          fileLastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
      End With

      Do Until counterRow = fileLastRow + 1
          Do Until counterCol = fileLastCol + 1
              fileString = fileString & Chr$(34) & fileWorksheet.Cells(counterRow, counterCol).Value & Chr$(34)
              If counterCol <> fileLastCol Then
                  fileString = fileString & fileDelimiter
              End If
              counterCol = counterCol + 1
          Loop
          binaryStream.WriteText fileString, 1
          counterRow = counterRow + 1
          counterCol = 1
          fileString = vbNullString
      Loop

      binaryStream.SaveToFile fileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
      binaryStream.Close
      MsgBox "CSV generated successfully"
      WriteOutputCSV = True
      Sheets(fileWorksheet.Name).UsedRange.Delete

  End Function
  ```

Comment: Seems `progressBarCount` could be local to `ConvertPanel` and a parameter to `SplitColumns`... is it used in another module? Because from the posted code I'm not sure what warrants `'@Ignore MoveFieldCloserToUsage`, which seems a correct suggestion from Rubberduck.

Comment: Hi @Mat'sMug! Yes it used in a separate class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small note about the elephant in the room:

> ```
>         If finalProcessor Then
>             If FormatYear Then
>                 If FormatAutocomm Then
>                     If FormatID Then
>                         If FormatHA Then
>                             If FormatProv Then
>                                 If AddHeader Then
>                                     If ReplaceSpaces Then
>                                         If CleanupSpaces Then
>                                             If WriteOutputCSV Then
> ```

Each and every single one of these `Boolean`-returning functions should be a `Sub`: they all have side-effects on the data, and if *one* of them fails, *everything* needs to abort.

This looks like a job for... custom error handling! That way you can flatten up that smelly arrow code and turn it into a sequence of operations:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    '...

        finalProcessor
        FormatYear
        FormatAutocomm
        FormatID
        FormatHA
        FormatProv
        AddHeader
        ReplaceSpaces
        CleanupSpaces

        'temporal coupling: everything above must run before this one
        WriteOutputCSV

    '...
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
```

You can have each of these functions either bubble up any run-time error that occurs, or raise custom ones with a descriptive message that the "coordinator" procedure displays before exiting.

For example:

```
Private Sub ValidateSpecString(ByVal specString As String)

     If Len(specString) < 3 Then
        Err.Raise ERR_INVALID_SPEC, "ValidateSpecString", "No spec found. Please re-check."
     End If

    If specString = vbNullString Then
        Err.Raise ERR_INVALID_SPEC, "ValidateSpecString", "Field specs are incorrect or missing. Aborting!"
    End If

    If InStr(specString, "|") = 0 Then
        Err.Raise ERR_INVALID_SPEC, "ValidateSpecString", "Please specify that you have at least 2 fields. Example: 1,10|2,10"
    End If

End Function
```

This has the added benefit of moving the concern of *telling the user why the macro is failing* in one single place, so you have one single error-displaying `MsgBox` instead of 12 (and one single "success" message).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm actually learning how to custom error, and that actually helps me so much!

Answer (score 2):

To take a stab at the arrow issue, an alternative would be something similar to:

```
    If Not ValidateSpecString(specString) Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not ValidateInputFile(filePath) Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)

    convertString = ConvertSpecString(specString)
    readMethod = QuickRead(filePath)
    finalProcessor = SplitColumns(readMethod, convertString, startCell)


    If Not finalProcessor Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not FormatYear Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not FormatAutocomm Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not FormatID Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not FormatHA Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not FormatProv Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not AddHeader Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not ReplaceSpaces Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not CleanupSpaces Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)
    If Not WriteOutputCSV Then HandleError (CustomErrorInfo)

    ExcelOptimization (False)

    MsgBox "Process completed and file generated!", vbOKOnly, "Complete!"
```

Admittedly, this is uglier than Mat's Mug's approach, but this is the approach I use because it suits my style and needs a bit more. The benefit here is that you can choose your approach to handling the error. So, for example, handling an error in the `FormatYear` routine can be different than handling an error in the `FormatID` routine. I also avoid `On Error` statements as much as a possibly can. There isn't anything *wrong* with them when used well, but I try to anticipate errors if I can.

On that note, and as others have noted, some of your subroutines need some cleanup. Someone in the RD group recently reminded me of the 'Single Responsibility Principle'. Everything should be responsible for *one* thing, and in turn, that thing should align with it's own intent. Along these lines, I would argue, that one unique thing should only ever be returned by one *owner* of sorts. For example:

```
Private Function GetSpecString() As String

    Dim customSpecString As Long
    customSpecString = MsgBox("Do you want to use default spec string?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Custom spec string")

    If customSpecString = vbNo Then
        GetSpecString = Application.InputBox("Enter your custom string", "Custom string builder", Type:=2)

        If GetSpecString = False Then
            MsgBox "No string was chosen. The default string will be used."
            GetSpecString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,2,@|29,2,@|34,1"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Else
        GetSpecString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,3,@|29,2,@|34,1"
        Exit Function
    End If

End Function
```

Can you find the one difference I made between the first GetSpecString and the second? How long did it take you to find it? This was done to prove a point of course, but imagine if you, in all your wisdow, edited the first spec string, but forgot to make the same change to the second. Now you have two possible 'routes' your code can take, and it will take you forever to figure out why. Something like:

```
Function DefaultSpecString() as String
    DefaultSpecString = "1,10,@|11,2,@|15,1,@|16,4,@|20,2,@|23,1,@|31,1,@|35,1,@|39,1,@|41,1,@|160,1,@|161,2,@|163,1,@|165,1,@|25,2,@|29,2,@|34,1"
End Function
```

And you can use it like this:

```
Private Function GetSpecString() As String
    Dim customSpecString As Long
    customSpecString = MsgBox("Do you want to use default spec string?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Custom spec string")

    If customSpecString = vbNo Then
        GetSpecString = Application.InputBox("Enter your custom string", "Custom string builder", Type:=2)

        ' Note : A string shouldn't be a boolean False. Check this and find a better way of determining
        ' whether the user input a valid string. Keeping it as is for proof of concept though.
        If GetSpecString <> False Then Exit Function
    End If

    GetSpecString = DefaultSpecString
End Function
```

Notice how I ensure that only *one* line has responsibility over setting the return of the function to the default string. If the user chooses not to enter a custom string, then the function skips the If block and sets the string. If the user enters an invalid string it ignores the `If ... Exit Function` and again sets it to the default string.

Always try to strive for this. It will make your debugging that much easier. Otherwise, if you do the same thing in two places, and it breaks, you have to fix it in two places. I can't tell you how many hours that has cost me before I learned to code smarter.

Finally, my last note is this, and it is somewhat counter intuitive to my first suggestion: if you are relying on Boolean returns, and "On Error" statements to catch errors, you can improve. Look at *why* it breaks, and then try to handle that specific issue. As Mat's Mug mentioned, bubble it up if you can.

In my most recent project I am aggregating a fairly complex report, and if even one of the sub reports fails it could invalidate the data. Instead of checking for errors at every juncture, I let the functions return empty arrays if they fail, otherwise they return the data they were supposed to. In my aggregation routine, I check to see if there is data in the input, and if not I handle it appropriately. I also alert the user to what data is missing, and where I am trying to use it. As a result, the routine fails productively, and I can then trace it back down to determine what went wrong.

Overall though, 17 seconds for a routine to run isn't too bad. Youre likely taking the biggest performance hit on the fileread, and on the formatting on the worksheet (any time you perform operations on the worksheet it will *cost* you more than it would if you did it in memory).

Comment: thank you so much for the great review! The observation about the default string is really clever and I'll implement it! Great job :)

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to @MatsMug 's excellent suggestion on custom error handling, in cases where I've needed to combine a large number of `Boolean` flags to determine if processing can continue, I've used the multiplicative property of Boolean values to make it easier to read. As an example, your nested logic would become:

```
Dim everythingsGood as Boolean
everythingsGood = finalProcessor * FormatYear * _
                  FormatAutocomm * FormatID * _
                  FormatHA * FormatProv * AddHeader * _
                  ReplaceSpaces * CleanupSpaces

If everythingsGood Then
    WriteOutputCSV
End If
```

This method also benefits from @MatsMug 's custom error handling, as above. In the above case, the lack of an error by default passes processing to the next stage. For a set of `Boolean`-returning functions, this `everythingsGood` flag is arguably unnecessary.

Comment: Would it be bettor to use `And` instead? Is there a benefit of using `*` instead that I'm unaware of?

Comment: @IvenBach - `False = 0`, `True <> 0` so by multiplying, you end up with a `0` if any one function returns `False`. Actually, quite clever and I'd never thought of that... Unfortunately, because VBA doesn't shortcut evaluation in any way it appears that _all_ the functions must run in this method before `everythingGood` is set and can be checked, instead of stopping on the first failure. That could be good or bad, depending on how you want/handle error reporting - stop & report the first error, or attempt all processing & report all errors.

Comment: That's what I thought. I'll err on the side of caution and stick with `And` boolean operator and not go with clever code. I've been bitten too many times doing that. Duly noted about the full evaluation of everything.

Comment: The only real downside to the multiplicative property in this case is that all evaluations have to run before the final evaluation can be made. For a 17 second routine it is negligible, but if you were to use this approach on a larger routine it could cost you in the long run. Additionally, if you do something like a * b * c, but c is dependant on b, you will encounter two errors (the initial error in b and the error in c when it can't get what it needs from b).